# Azure Logic App - Built In vs Managed connectors

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, multi-tenant, connector

Apologies if this is a silly question but for the last 2 hrs. I have been reading about the difference between built-in and managed connectors for Azure logic apps and it's driving me crazy. Can someone please explain in simpler language? Initially, I thought built-in connectors are for Azure services like Azure function or table storage whereas managed are for Microsoft services like O365 & Sharepoint, but after going through the list of connectors on Microsoft documentation, its not true.

Is this tenant based? For example, built-in connector will only allow connecting to azure services in that tenant but if we need to connect to an Azure service in a different tenant, we need managed connector. Even if this is true, how can something like SMTP be an inbuilt connector?

Is the difference on the basis of authentication? The mechanism to authenticate is different for built-in / managed

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some differences between the two under the hood regarding how they are hosted, but I don't know how much difference that makes for you as a user. You can read a bit more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/compare-built-in-azure-connectors).

However, the main difference that I have noticed and that makes me prefer the built-in connectors (when applicable) is how you can set up the authentication. Especially when trying to set up CI-CD for Logic Apps (and devloping locally in VS Code) this makes a big difference. For the managed connectors, a managed api connection is created in the portal and it's a nightmare trying to parameterize that when developing in VS Code and incorporating that to Devops-pipelines.

Comment: thank you for ending my misery. The link u gave is very clear and now things make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in connectors run in the same platform where your logic apps is hosted whereas Managed connectors are hosted in public cloud. When you use built-in connectors the information configured for the connector will not be sent to public cloud for processing it will run natively in your Logic Apps. This makes it more secured. There are many differences for example authentication method, api connection file, and many more.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Logic Apps, there are two main types of connectors: built-in connectors and managed connectors.

1. **Built-in Connectors**: These are connectors that come pre-installed with Azure Logic Apps. They are developed and maintained by Microsoft and cover a wide range of services such as Azure Blob Storage, Azure SQL Database, Office 365, etc. Built-in connectors offer basic functionality for interacting with these services directly within your logic app workflows.
   Examples: Azure Blob Storage Connector,Azure SQL Database Connector.
2. **Managed Connectors**: Managed connectors, also known as custom connectors, are connectors created and managed by third-party developers or your organization. They allow you to extend the capabilities of Logic Apps by integrating with custom APIs or services that aren't covered by the built-in connectors. Managed connectors are typically created using Azure API Management and Azure Functions and can provide more tailored and specific functionality for your integration needs.
   Examples: Salesforce Connector,Twilio Connector,Custom API Connector

Here are some key differences between the two:

- **Availability**: Built-in connectors are readily available within Azure Logic Apps, whereas managed connectors need to be created and configured before they can be used in your logic app workflows.
- **Functionality**: Built-in connectors cover a broad range of commonly used services and provide basic functionality for interacting with them. Managed connectors can be tailored to specific use cases and can provide more advanced functionality by integrating with custom APIs or services.
- **Maintenance**: Microsoft maintains and updates built-in connectors, ensuring compatibility and reliability. Managed connectors require ongoing maintenance by the connector owner or organization to ensure they remain up-to-date and functional.
- **Flexibility**: Managed connectors offer greater flexibility as they can be customized to fit your specific integration requirements. Built-in connectors provide standardized functionality for common services but may not cover all use cases.

In summary, built-in connectors provide out-of-the-box integration with commonly used services, while managed connectors offer the flexibility to integrate with custom APIs or services tailored to your specific needs. The choice between the two depends on your integration requirements and the services you need to connect with in your logic app workflows.

You can find the exact details in this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/introduction